# Accessing variables from included files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, include

How do you access variables which are defined in an included file?

```
# inc.rb
foo = "bar";


# main.rb
require 'inc.rb'
puts foo

# NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't access a local outside of the scope it was defined in — the file in this case. If you want variables that cross file boundaries, make them anything but locals. `$foo`, `Foo` and `@foo` will all work.

If you just really don't want to put any sort of decoration on the symbol (because you don't like the way it reads, maybe), a common hack is just to define it as a method: `def foo() "bar" end`.

Comment: In which Ruby version this changed? I've been using it so since forever with Vagrant config

Answer (score 6):

I've accepted Chuck's answer because it's a decent solution, however I actually used a different method, which I thought I'd share. It's incredibly hacky, but was useful for my purposes. I needed to scan a directory with hundreds of files, each of which created an object with the same name, and then dump some info about each object. For any serious and non-temporary purposes, I *would not* recommend this!

```
foo = ""
eval File.open('inc.rb').read

puts foo # "bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually just define them as methods. Similar to what nickf said.

File1:

```
def static_path
  '/opt/foo'
end
```

File2:

```
static_path
```

Then just add a:

`require_relative 'file path/file name'` or `require_relative 'file name'` <= if files are in same dir.

to the file you want to use the method/variable in.